Dectect deleted element using XMLUnit
I´m comparing 2 xmls and trying to detect element deletion.
Old:
<a>
    <b>
        Text 1
    </b>
    <b>
        Text 2
    </b>
    <b>
        Text 3
    </b>
</a>

new:
<a>
    <b>
        Text 2
    </b>
    <b>
        Text 3
    </b>
</a>

The result that I was expecting is:
Deleted element:/a[1]/b[1]
But XmlUnit returns

It compares every node and mark the last one as deleted.
I have already tried ElementSelector.byNameAndText.
For this example it works fine but, all other text changes that I may have in the XMl it does not return Text Changed. It returns node deleted and added.
Any ideas how to make it works and if it is possible?
Thanks!
